# How to update data table by random?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a two tables:

- `subject` with the `columns id` and `n_contact_id`.
- `n_contact` with the columns `id`, `firstname`, `lastname`, and
  `secondname`.

Please help to update n_contact_id in subject table, but randomly:

```
UPDATE subject sub set n_contact_id = ...
```

Comment: No need to bold all that text.

Comment: if you can help help if there is no need to fix my mistakes, I do not know very well in English

Answer (score 0):

This code will do it where you know the id of the subject you want to change. Just insert the subject id (either manually or with an extracted variable) in the SUBJECT_ID_HERE variable.

```
UPDATE subject as sub,
(
    SELECT id FROM n_contact order by RAND() LIMIT 1
) as temp
SET n_contact_id = temp.id WHERE sub.id = SUBJECT_ID_HERE
```

The one caveat is RAND() is slow for tables with an exceptionally large amount of rows, but for small tables will do just fine.